# SQL Server Integration Services tutorial for AdventureWorks > AdventureWorksDW export

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I'm getting started with building a Business Intelligence system using MS technologies.
I don't have any experience with Integration Services or with Analysis Services, so the learning curve is pretty steep for me.

I have been looking for samples and tutorials and found some nice stuff such as:

- The `AdventureWorksDW` data warehouse, which will help me build my own data warehouse.
- A nice BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) sample project for putting analysis on the `AdventureWorksDW`.
- Integration Services samples on http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/

But what I'm actually looking for is a sample BIDS Integration Services project that exports changes from the main `AdventureWorks DB` into the `AdventureWorksDW DB`.

I don't seem to find such project in the samples..

Or is there any other tutorial/video available that contains a step-by-step walktrough on copying data to your warehouse?

I have the book "MS SQL Server 2008 Integration Services Unleashed" but I don't know how to get started.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be exactly what the first package on Codeplex does:

> The AWDataWarehouseRefresh sample package illustrates how to create and populate user tables in the new AdvWorksDWX database, using data from the AdventureWorks database.

Have you tried running it?

I don't want to sound harsh, but you already have sample databases, sample code and a book on using SSIS so I'm not really sure why you're unable to get started. Have you read the book and installed, executed and understood a few sample packages? If not, I suggest that you give it a try, then come back and ask about specific problems you're having. Unfortunately it's hard to know what to suggest right now: this isn't a suitable forum for explaining basic concepts, but it is a great forum for answering specific questions.

Comment: That example creates a fresh, seperate DB with a query + fills it up from csv files. As I'm said I'm just getting started, but that doesn't sound like a best practice. I'm still going trough the book on SSIS.

Comment: I figured there must be an example project somewhere that syncs changes from the AdventureWorks DB into the existing AdventureWorksDW DB.. I can't image they would supply us with both of those database samples but no real-life'ish samples of interaction between them.

Comment: Bump. Would love to have a sample package that illustrates how to create and populate user tables in a new database, using data from the AdventureWorks database.